# Query JSON Owned Entity collection could not be translated

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

We are currently using the latest preview version of Entity Framework Core (8.0.0-preview.7.23375.4) because we have a JSON data structure saved inside a column.

To make it easier to search into that data structure, we were looking at using the `OwnsMany` in combination with `ToJson`.

We basically have something like this:

```
// DbContext
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Signal>(entity =>
    {
         // bunch of properties
         entity.OwnsMany(
            e => e.Details, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
            {
                ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
                ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsMany(c => c.Values, b =>
                {
                     // inner owned collection of entities
                });
            }
        );
    }
}

// Signal Entity
public class Signal
{
     // properties
     public List<InnerEntity>? Details { get; set; }
}

// Inner entity
public class InnerEntity
{
      public string Step { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to query the `Signal` by using something along the following code, it returns that the query can't be translated (without using AsEnumerable, ToList() …)

```
.Where(s => s.Details.Any(s => s.Step == "2"));
```

From our understanding, it seemed that the issues related to querying JSON were fixed [28616](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28616), [31369](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/31369).

Is this feature available already in the current preview? If so, are we doing something wrong? Is it related to the `Any()`? (We also tried with other ways like `.Select(…).Contains()` and it always failed).

Edit: the error message is the following:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet().Where(s => EF.Property<List>(s, "Details").AsQueryable().Any(o => o.Step == "2"))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: Looks like not released yet, but try to remove `s.Details != null` - it may cause problem.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I did remove the `s.Details != null`, but it still didn't work. I will update the original post to remove it there as it is not related to the issue. I will also put the proper error message as well as it could probably help. Thanks